# Wifi not turning on/Stuck on "Turning on...", is there any other solution

Tags: wi-fi, factory-reset

I have a tablet (tab s6 lite) but there is a problem, when i connected the tablet to my (old) macbook,it started going crazy

It kept on resetting and the wifi would not work

I fixed the first problem, but not the second

I really want this to get fixed soon, and i know this is a common question, and i know i **might** need to factory reset or repair it but i have alot of data and i am fine
with reparing it, but i will Happily accept any other solution

(I couldn't put a recording here so this is what happens)

if i open setting and turn on wifi then it gets stuck on "Turning on...", but if i go back and then open wifi settings again, it will be turned off

Same for the Control Center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to you to totally shut down the phone.
Shutting it down powers off a lot components which is like a hard reset.

Usually one would expect that there is no difference between shutting down a phone and power it on again to a reboot but it seems that unser some rare conditions some chips can enter a state that is not affected by a reboot. Only powering of the chip can solve such problems.

I had this once with the GPS chip in my phone. No matter what I did it wasn't working properly. Only shutting down the phone, wait some seconds and then start it again restored it's functionality.